# Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for NonMaxSuppressionV3: ERROR

Tags: tensorflow, non-maximum-suppression

I'm facing this error while trying to use tf.image.non_max_suppression while video object detection. Tensorflow version is 1.10.0

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for
>   'non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV3' (op: 'NonMaxSuppressionV3')
>   with input shapes: [1,500,4], [1,500], [], [], [].

Comment: Could you post some code to illustrute your attempt to solve as well as description of the problem you faced?

Comment: I'm using tensorflow to detect object in Video. when I called the pre build function " tf.image.non_max_suppression " the error mentioned earlier came up. 
selected_indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(boxes, scores, 3, 0.6)

selected_boxes = tf.gather(boxes, selected_indices)

Comment: thanks a lot, bassma, it would be nice if you edit your question and add the information in the comment into the text.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same error with tensorflow2.1 and the reason is that (as it says in the error) that the batch dimension cannot be there.

> tf.image.non_max_suppression(
> boxes, scores, max_output_size, iou_threshold=0.5,
> score_threshold=float('-inf'), name=None )
>
> boxes A 2-D float Tensor of shape [num_boxes, 4].

Example:

```
selected_indices = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
    boxes=boxes,
    scores=scores,
    max_output_size=7,
    iou_threshold=0.5)
```

You should remove the first(batch) dimension of the tensors (boxes and scores in the example above)
In case your batch dimension is 1 you can use

```
boxes = tf.squeeze(boxes)
scores = tf.squeeze(scores)
```

It seems that you can have batch dimension is in this beast:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/combined_non_max_suppression